# Passing variable to jQuery on() method

Tags: jquery, events, delegates

How can I make this jQuery code to work? I have cashed some element in "someVariable" and I want to use it in on() method like this:

```
function test() {
    var elementsBlock = $('.elements-block'),
        someVariable1 = elementsBlock.find('.some-el-1'),
        someVariable2 = elementsBlock.find('.some-el-2'),
        ...
        someVariableN = elementsBlock.find('.some-el-n');

    // some code

    elementsBlock.on('click', someVariableN, function() {
        // do sth
    });
}

test();
```

I want to pass variable in arguments, not selector (".some-el-n"). Is it possible? If I run this function, event works for "elementsBlock" not for "someVariableN" only.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. Well... instead of someVariableN.on('click', function() {...}) or someVariableN.click(function() {...}); I wanted to use this form of on() method because I read that it's faster than two mentioned methods.

Comment: Well... before improving the performance, you should try to see if there's really a performance issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. With [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) you have to use a selector. It is used for capturing clicks on dynamically created elements. If you already know the elements that exist, you don't need event delegation:

```
someVariableN.on('click', function() {
    // do sth
});
```

If you wanted to attach variables that started with class `some-el`, you could use event delegation:

```
elementsBlock.on('click', '[class^="some-el"]', function() {
    // do sth
});
```

But if none of those elements are created dynamically, then the following line would do the same thing:

```
$('[class^="some-el"]').on('click', function() {
    // do sth
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit odd to many programmers coming from other languages but in JavaScript, you can access variables declared outside the function.  (Take a look at [w3school JavaScipt closures](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) if you want an example)

In your case, it means that you could access `someVariableN` without passing it as a parameter:

```
function test() {
    var elementsBlock = $('.elements-block'),
        someVariable1 = elementsBlock.find('.some-el-1'),
        someVariable2 = elementsBlock.find('.some-el-2'),
        ...
        someVariableN = elementsBlock.find('.some-el-n');

    elementsBlock.on('click', function() {
        alert(someVariableN.length);  //You can use someVariableN here
    });
}
```